# conversion from string "" to 'date' is not valid vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have following code

```
LastLeaveDt = DispName(con, "Select max(dtLeave) from EmpLeave where Empid='" & eid.Text & "' and year(dtleave)='" & cmbYear.Text & "'")

Public Function DispName(cn As ADODB.Connection, mQRY As String) As String
    Dim xrs1 As New ADODB.Recordset
    Try
        xrs1.Open(mQRY, cn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenForwardOnly)
        If xrs1.EOF = False Then
            DispName = IIf(IsDBNull(xrs1(0).Value), "", xrs1(0).Value)
        End If
        xrs1.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

In this code at run time it is giving me error "Conversion From String "" To 'Date' is not valid"

Comment: Try to debug, dude.

Comment: Do you not understand the message (in which case google it), or do you not understand how to debug it? Somewhere you are trying to convert a string (which is empty) into a date. We can't see your data or the values of your variables, and we can't see any variables which are of the DateTime or Date type, and you haven't given a line number, so we can't say for definite where the problem is. However Tim's guess is a sensible one. The value of dtLeave itself could also be a problem, if that's a held as a string in the DB (and not a date)

Comment: What date should `""` represent, in your very personal vision?

Comment: As a side note: the `If` operator should be used in place of that old `IIf` function.  An it is more in keeping with NET to use the `Return` statement rather than assigning the result VB6 style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change your code as :

```
 If xrs1.EOF = False Then
        If IsDate (IsDBNull(xrs1(0).Value)) then
             DispName = xrs1(0).Value
         else
             DispName =""
        End If
   End If
```